# Upload de imagem com problema no nodejs

Tags: node.js

Estou realizando uns teste para implementar um upload de imagem e criei o seguinte código no back-end no node js.

```
function uploadImagem (req, res) {
    var restauranteId = req.params.id;
    var file_name = 'No subido...';

    if(req.files){
        var file_path = req.files.image.path;
        var file_split = file_path.split('\\');
        var file_name = file_split[2];

        res.status(200).send({
            file_path: file_path,
            file_split: file_split,
            file_name: file_name
        });
    }else{
        res.status(200).send({message: 'não a solicitação de usuário'});
    }

        
}
```

Quando vou submeter o dados ele somente cai na condição abaixo;

```
    else{
            res.status(200).send({message: 'não a solicitação de usuário'});
        }
```

Eu estou fazendo assim;
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O resultado esperado era para ser parecido com esse;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como conseguir contornar essa situação?

Realizando a sugestão de @Thiago Magalhães o método ficou assim;

```
function uploadImagem (req, res) {
    res.status(200).send({message: req.body.fles});
    var restauranteId = req.params.id;
    var file_name = 'No subido...';

    if(req.files){
        var file_path = req.files.image.path;
        var file_split = file_path.split('\\');
        var file_name = file_split[2];

        res.status(200).send({
            file_path: file_path,
            file_split: file_split,
            file_name: file_name
        });
    }else{
        res.status(200).send({message: 'não a solicitação de usuário'});
    }

        
}
```

Eu não tenho como usar o `console.log()` porque é um teste realizado no back-end, então utilizei o `res.status(200).send({message: req.body.fles});` , testei também com o `res.status(200).send({message: req.body.image});` 
Porém os dois resultado dar `{}` vazia.

Comment: veja se a imagem não está indo para `req.body.image` ou `req.body.files`

Comment: Como eu faço para saber ?

Comment: coloca essa duas opções que falei dentro de um `console.log()` logo no inicio da sua função `uploadImagem`.. e veja no console se encontra as informações da imagem enviada

Comment: @ThiagoMagalhães eu fiz uma atualização na postagem dar uma olhada por favor.

Comment: Está dando um valor vazio em ambos os casos `{}`

Comment: Eu coloquei o `console.log(req.files);` antes do if e o resultado foi  `undefined` no MSDOS, por que será que está acontecendo isso?

Comment: Então dessa forma ai você vai ter que fazer na unha como nesse [exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36276149/how-to-get-the-values-from-postman-extention-form-data-values). Eu particularmente prefiro usar o multer, só criar um middleware antes da request.

Comment: achei bem complicado  :/

Comment: Com multer é muito simples, com 3 linhas tu faz o upload do arquivo.